# can't use Zxing libraries on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, zxing

I can't use Zxing Libraries on android studio. it's give error was not found in libraries

I need use zyxing for qr scanner app but its not work on android studio
I ınstalled zyxing followed this steps:

Added dependencies in build.gradle files

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
}
```

added permission in AndroidManifest.xml files

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and last step imported library in MainActivity.java

```
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;
```

But result is sad :(

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add exception from logcat

Comment: @MidasLefko This isn't a runtime error. But they should add the build error from the Build tab in Android Studio if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

yes, we can use zxing library in Android studio

```
     repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0'
}
```

Please Follow Below link from Github

https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

Comment: It is already my problem. I am pass all steps perfectly but later give same error unfortunately

Comment: you have used different library version. Please use as I suggested version

Comment: pls write true code for me bro